# Determine Limit for Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

$P(t):$

$\frac{dP}{dt} = cP  \ln(\frac{K}{P})$

where c is a parameter and $∀t≥0 : P(t)≤K$

Determine: $\lim\limits_{t\to ∞} P(t)$

I don't understand what $P(t)$ even looks like with $∞$ plugged in.

How do I write $P(t)$ so I can then calculate the Limit?

Comment: does $Pln$ mean $P\cdot \ln$?

Comment: @5xum Yes it does

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = cP\ln(\frac{K}{P}) =cP\left(\ln(K)-\ln(P) \right) $$

THE ARDUOUS WAY :

Change of function :
$$P(t)=e^{y(t)} \quad\to\quad \frac{dP}{dt} = e^{y(t)}\frac{dy}{dt} $$
and $\quad\frac{dP}{dt}=cP\left(\ln(K)-\ln(P) \right) =c e^{y(t)} \left(\ln(K)-y(t) \right) $
$$e^{y(t)}\frac{dy}{dt}=c e^{y(t)} \left(\ln(K)-y(t) \right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+c\:y(t)=c\ln(K)$$
This is a first order linear ODE. I let you solve it for $y(t)$.
Finally : 
$$P(t)=K\exp\left(C_0\:e^{-c\:t} \right)$$
$C_0=$arbitrary constant.

$t\to\infty\quad\implies\quad P\to K$ .

THE SMART WAY :

Suppose $P(t)$ tends to a limit when $t\to\infty$

This implies $\quad\frac{dP}{dt}\to 0.\quad$ Hense $\quad cP\ln(\frac{K}{P}) \to 0.\quad$

This is possible only if $\quad\frac{K}{P}\to 1.$

Hense $\quad P\to K$.

Comment: Why does it imply that?

Comment: When $P(t)$ tends to a finite and constant limit $=C$ , then dP/dt = dC/dt=0.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$P=k e^{-\sqrt{\frac{1}{ct+d}}}$$ which gives $k$ as the limit

For obtaining the above rewrite the differential equation as $$\frac{dP}{P \ln{k/P}}= cdt$$ and then integrate

Comment: How do you write $P$ in that form?

Comment: I got $ - ln(ln(\frac{K}{P}) = cx$ did I mess up or how should I proceed

Comment: No you can write $\frac{dP}{P \ln{k/P}}$ as $$-\frac{d[\ln{k/P}]}{\ln{k/P}}$$

Comment: Sorry I don't how you do that